# append css inline styles in js button for hover

Tags: javascript, css

im trying to set a different backgroundcolor from a button with an variable. the normal background is not a problem but when i want to change on hover it doesnt work. what am i doing wrong?

```
'<a href="'+data.weblink+'" target="_blank"><button style="background-color: '+color[1]+'; onMouserOver=backgroud-color:'+color[2]+'" class="template9_link_button">'+data.buttontext+'</button></a>';
```

so link and background is not a problem but hover or onMouseOver seems not to work.
any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of generating inline styles, generate a style tag, so you can then add :hover pseudo class

Comment: can i still use a variable from js?

Comment: You can use `css-in-js` if you want. There are many libraries for this particular use case.

Comment: `this.style.backgroundColor = color[1]`